# Downloading Chromium r624492... ERROR: Failed to download Chromium r624492

Tags: node.js

Installed ndb successfully
PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD=1 sudo npm install -g ndb --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root ftw
[sudo] password for jibril:

changed 144 packages in 1m

5 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details
But having an error when I am trying to run ndb server.js

```
ndb server.js
Downloading Chromium r624492...
ERROR: Failed to download Chromium r624492!
Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ndb/node_modules/carlo/lib/.local-data'
  -- ASYNC --
    at BrowserFetcher.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ndb/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/helper.js:108:27)
    at downloadChromium (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ndb/node_modules/carlo/lib/find_chrome.js:194:50)
    at findChrome (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ndb/node_modules/carlo/lib/find_chrome.js:241:32)
    at Object.launch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ndb/node_modules/carlo/lib/carlo.js:594:42)
    at launch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ndb/lib/launcher.js:23:23)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ndb/ndb.js:35:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12) {
  errno: -13,
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'mkdir',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ndb/node_modules/carlo/lib/.local-data'
}
unhandledRejection TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'executablePath')
    at findChrome (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ndb/node_modules/carlo/lib/find_chrome.js:242:43)
    at async Object.launch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ndb/node_modules/carlo/lib/carlo.js:594:36)
    at async launch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ndb/lib/launcher.js:23:11)
```